Why Chrome tab memory keeps growing and heap size stays the same until it runs out of memory?


I tried to analyze the memory snapshot using chrome memory tool,
As well as trying to use the performance analysis tool,
so far I have not found the reason, is it possible to debug the contents of memory footprint. My project is mainly a canvas 2d rendering, I hope you can give me ideas on how to debug it.
